# Popper.js: How to close popup when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, popper.js

I'm using [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/) to show a popup elment having the class `.js-share-cf-popover`  when clicking elements with class `.js-share-cf-btn`.

But I want the popup to close only when I click outside of it. Here my actual code that show the popup:

```
var reference = $('.js-share-cf-btn');
var popover = $('.js-share-cf-popover');
popover.hide();

$(document).on('click', reference, function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  popover.show();

  var popper = new Popper(reference, popover, {
    placement: 'top',
  });
});
```

I found something [here](https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/issues/300) but I can't get it works

Here My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/42053/)

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle ? It ll be easier to help you

Comment: Hi @QuentinRoger jsfiddle added in my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this, by removing event delegation and checking the target on event click by using the [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/), (compare e.target if it equals to the referencing button, otherwise hide the popup)

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/44982/)

Added snippet as your code :

also made change in the `Popper` instance you should pass the current click `js-share-cf-btn` so the `$(e.target)` element

```js
$(function() {
  var reference = $('.js-share-cf-btn');
  var popover = $('.js-share-cf-popover');
  popover.hide();

  $(document).on('click touchend', function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    // ne need to reshow and recreate popper when click over popup so return;
    if(target.is(popover)) return;
    if (target.is(reference)) {
      e.preventDefault();

      popover.show();

      var popper = new Popper(target, popover, {
        placement: 'top',
      });
    }else {
      popover.hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.section {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.share-popover {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="section">
  <p>Section 1</p>
  <a href="#" class="js-share-cf-btn">This is the trigger</a>
</div>

<div class="section">
  <p>Section 2</p>
  <a href="#" class="js-share-cf-btn">This is the trigger</a>
</div>

<div class="section">
  <p>Section 3</p>
  <a href="#" class="js-share-cf-btn">This is the trigger</a>
</div>

<div class="share-popover js-share-cf-popover">
  This is the popup
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, when I click inside the popup it closes. I want it close only when clicking outside it.

Comment: @FredK added fiddle and snippet as you discribed , https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/44982/ Does it work ?

Comment: You could replace `click` event with `click touch` for covering also mobile devices.

Comment: Or maybe `click touchend`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the trick (by checking the target when you are clicking somewhere):

```
$(function() {
  var ref = $('.js-share-cf-btn');
  var popover = $('.js-share-cf-popover');
  popover.hide();

  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (target.is(ref) || target.is(popover) ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      popover.show();
      var popper = new Popper(ref, popover, {
        placement: 'right',
      });
    }else {
      popover.hide();
    }
  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e8aL9tje/

Comment: Hi, I have multiple button: when click on a button your code shows the popup for every buttons. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/tdo2efrs/

Comment: Is something like this better ? https://jsfiddle.net/hovaqnxz/ Have a great day !

Comment: It's an improvement but it remains something strange: click first button then click second button. Result: I get the 2 popups opened, while the first one should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

For those using React, I created a gist of an HOC that you can attach to any component to close it when clicked outside:

https://gist.github.com/elie222/850bc4adede99650508aba2090cd5da1

Answer (score 0):

I found a really simple solution to this.

**jQuery version**

```html
<div class="Popper">
    <div class="stopPropagation">
        <p>Clicking on me won't close the Popper</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.stopPropagation').on('click touchend', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
})
```

Since the click event does not propagate up to the Popper, the Popper will not closed when clicked.

**React version**

```html
<Popper>
    {/* eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events */}
    <div onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()} role="none">
        <p>Clicking on me won't close the Popper</p>
    </div>
</Popper>
```